# Dynamically Creating a table and inserting Rows inside a SP

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert

I am trying to run a Stored Procedure that Inserts into a Table.
I keep getting the Incorrect syntax near 'tbl_1_2'.
It doesn't Insert the data.I am using MSSQL2012

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[TT] AS 
BEGIN

declare @tbl varchar(100);
set @tbl='tbl_1_2';

declare @sql varchar(100);
DECLARE @ptablename VARCHAR(max) = (@tbl)

set @ptablename=@tbl
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @ptablename ;

EXEC  (@sql)

select * 
from   (
           values('1','2')
       ) t1 (c1, c2)

End
```

Comment: You havn't declared `@tblSET`

Comment: Try do a `PRINT @sql` and inspect your query. Note I have formatted your query.

Comment: Print @sql give ms INSERT INTO tbl_1_2.

Answer (score 0):

See this sample and compare with your code to understand your error.

```
Create Table Test (ID int, Name sysname)
Go

Declare @TableName sysname = 'Test'
DECLARE @ID int = 1
DECLARE @Name sysname = 'Meysam'
Declare @SQL nVarchar(4000) = 'INSERT @TableName (ID, Name) Values (@ID, N''@Name'')'

Set @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@TableName', @TableName)
Set @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@ID', @ID)
Set @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@Name', @Name)

EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT * FROM Test
```